# 香皂 vs. 肥皂: What's the difference?

Tags: difference

### 香皂

> scented soap, toilet soap

### 肥皂

> soap

What's difference though?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is exactly as the definitions say. 香皂 is "**scented** soaps", while 肥皂 is just generic "soaps". That is the only difference. 香皂 is abbreviated from 香肥皂, meaning soap with added scents.

You can use either for washing face, body, hand, or clothes, but normally people use 洗衣粉/精 for the latter.

Comment: exactly. But seldom see anyone uses a 香皂 to wash his/her face, because it can easily hurt eyes.

Comment: We usually use 洗面乳／露 for washing our faces. Similarly, 沐浴乳／露 is bodywash.

Comment: Sure. But that's talking about what people like to *do* now, not what the words mean. Bar soaps used to be the norm anyway.

Answer (score 3):

香皂 is one type of 肥皂. normally 香皂 is only for cleaning human body when people clean hand and have a bath.

some other type of 肥皂 are clean something else, like cleaning clothes.

Answer (score 1):

香皂 is used for washing face/body, 肥皂 is used for washing clothes.

Answer (score 1):

香皂 is soap made out of "scented" (香) materials, hence **scented**  soap. 肥皂 is soap made from fat (肥), hence ordinary soap